# Kann das Verb "singen" die Funktion eines Kopulaverbes übernehmen?

Tags: verb, linking-elements

Im Englischen wird behauptet, dass das Verb "smell" -also riechen - die Funktion eines Kopulaverbes übernehmen kann, da, wenn jemand z.B. sagt "the flowers smell good", man versteht, dass "good" eine Eigenschaft von "flowers" beschreibt. 
Ich frage mich dann, ob das auch im Deutschen geschehen kann. Also, dass einige Verben, die nicht ursprünglich als Kopulaverben behauptet werden können, die Funktion eines solches Verbes übernehmen können. Zum Beispiel bei dem folgenden Satz:

> (1) Er singt gut.

Bedeutet dieser Satz nicht das Gleiche als der Satz "**Er ist ein guter Sänger**"?
Und wenn *singen* beim Satz (1) wie ein Kopulaverb funktionieren könnte, würde das dann heißen, dass "gut" ein Subjektsprädikativ ist?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 1. Nein

Ein Kopula ist ein Verb, das ein Satzglied an ein anderes bindet.

Beispiel 1:

> Walter ist Lehrer.

Hier bindet das Kopula *»ist«* das Wort *»Lehrer«* an *»Walter«*. Somit ist *»Lehrer«* etwas, das *»Walter«* beschreibt. (Das Wort *»Lehrer«* beschreibt nicht das Wort *»ist«*!)

Beispiel 2:

> Walter ist müde.
>   Walter ist gut.

Wie oben. Wo im Beispiel 1 ein Substantiv stand (*»Lehrer«*) steht nun ein Adjektiv (*»müde«* bzw. *»gut«*). Die Wörter *»müde«* und *»gut«* beschreiben *»Walter«*. Sie beschreiben nicht *»ist«*.

aber:

> Walter singt gut.

Hier wird *»gut«* nicht an *»Walter«* gebunden, sondern an »*singt«*. Das Adjektiv beschreibt keine Eigenschaft einer Person (*»Walter«*), sondern eine Eigenschaft einer Tätigkeit (*»singt«*).

Das, was hier vorliegt, ist der adverbiale Gebrauch eines Adjektivs.

Adjektive können auf drei Arten verwendet werden:

- attributiv (Begleiter eines anderen Wortes, meist eines Substantivs)

  > eine ungewöhnliche Lampe (Attribut eines Substantivs)
  >   eine ungewöhnlich helle Lampe (Attribut eines Adjektivs)
- prädikativ (bildet zusammen mit einem Kopula ein Prädikat welches das Subjekt beschriebt)

  > Diese Lampe ist ungewöhnlich.
  >   Seine Lebensgeschichte bleibt ungewöhnlich.
- adverbial (nachgestellter Begleiter eines Verbs, beschreibt eine Eigenschaft des Verbs)

  > Die Lampe leuchtet ungewöhnlich.
  >   Jürgen spricht ungewöhnlich.

---

### 2. Nein

Die Sätze

- Walter singt gut.
- Walter ist ein guter Sänger.

bedeuten nicht dasselbe. Walter ist nämlich auch dann ein guter Sänger, wenn er schläft, isst oder sonst etwas anderes macht. Walter ist immer ein guter Sänger.
Aber er singt nur dann gut, wenn er singt.

Es kann auch der Fall sein, dass Walter eigentlich gar nicht singen kann (also ein schlechter Sänger ist), aber als er beim Geburtstag von Tante Else *Happy Birthday* gesungen hat, hat das den Anwesenden trotzdem gut gefallen, und jemand hat dann gesagt, Walter würde gut singen.

Comment: 2. Kann ich als Muttersprachler nicht nachvollziehen. *Er spricht gut Französisch* bezieht sich auf das Können und ist auch wahr, wenn die Person gerade nicht am Sprechen ist.

Comment: "Walter singt gut" kann dasselbe bedeuten wie "Walter ist ein guter Sänger" oder es kann bedeuten, dass Walter gerade jetzt gut singt. Da dem Deutschen eine Verlaufsform wie im Englischen fehlt, ist das nicht eindeutig.

Comment: Möglicherweise ist der Sprachgebrauch diesbezüglich in österreichischem Deutsch anders als in deutschem Deutsch. In letzterem ist Teil 2 der Antwort jedenfalls falsch (Begründung siehe die Kommentare meiner beiden Vorredner)